# BlackBerry - how to occupy a complete button with image

Tags: image, blackberry, java-me, button

I have written BlackBerry code to add an image to a ButtonField. I want the whole button to be occupied by the image, but the image is not displayed completely on the ButtonField.
There is a lot of margin on the top, left and right of the button.  I tried to use cellpadding but it didn't work.

How can I reduce the width and height of the ButtonField so it matches the original image size of 41 x 41?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding an image to a button extend the image class and turn that into a button by overriding isFocusable(), navigationClick(), trackwheelClick(), and keyChar().  Here's the code:

```
public class ImageButtonField extends BitmapField
{
    public ImageButtonField(Bitmap image) {
        super(image);
    }

    public boolean isFocusable() {
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean keyChar(char character, int status, int time) {
        if(Characters.ENTER == character || Characters.SPACE == character) {
            fieldChangeNotify(0);
            return true;
        }
        return super.keyChar(character, status, time);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi jonathan.Thank you so much for such an instant reply.But i have added tool tip on the onfocus event of my ButtonField.Will i be able to do the same thing with a bitmap if i use that.please let me know about it

Comment: You can do the exact same thing with this class.  Every class that extends Field has the onFocus() method.

Comment: Thank You so much jonathan.I tried out the solution told by you and it worked perfectly.....Thank you so so much dear.:)