# Blackberry Custom Image button

Tags: blackberry, java-me

i have created a custom image button; one is **play** image button and one is **pause** image button.

i want to switch between **play** and **pause** (i.e when the user clicks on the button,it has to change - play to pause or pause to play).

for my requirement, i have referred to this [example url](http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/04/custom-image-button-in-bb.html)

when i execute my program, i am able to display the button, but when i click on the button, i am not able to change the imagebutton (play to pause)

can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example that you are working off of uses two images, the **on** and the **off** image.  However, it uses these two images to change the look of the button based on whether the button has *focus* or not.

You want something a little different.  You want to change the look of the button whenever the button gets *clicked*.  To do that, you can use this existing method:

```java
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
    fieldChangeNotify(1);
    return true;
}
```

To do this, change (or add) some member variables to store the play and pause bitmaps, and then change `navigationClick()` to toggle between them:

```java
private Bitmap _currentPicture;
private Bitmap _playPicture;
private Bitmap _pausePicture;

protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
    if (_currentPicture == _playPicture) {
        _currentPicture = _pausePicture;
    } else {
        _currentPicture = _playPicture;
    }
    invalidate();  // may be necessary to force redraw of the button

    fieldChangeNotify(1);
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:** you also might want to perform the same logic (as above in `navigationClick()`) in the `trackwheelClick()` and `keyChar()` methods, depending on whether your buttons should be *clickable* by using the trackwheel or enter keys, too.  [See an example of that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4509592/119114)